# Firebase Analytics Appcelerator Module for Android

Tags: firebase, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

Is there a module for Firebase Analytics that works for SDK 6 of Appcelerator? I've got one that works for iOS (https://github.com/chrisribe/ti-firebase) but I can't find one that works with Android. Does anybody have one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having the same issue researched a lot found lot of modules, but not satisfied have a look at the link : https://gist.github.com/FokkeZB/ed0694c3fe25e72e2080